# Bash on Ubuntu Server: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, exec, freebsd

I have the following script, which worked perfectly fine on FreeNas.
Now, using it on Ubuntu have the following error:

find: missing argument to `-exec'

```
#!/bin/bash

find /fileshare/Zund/export/ \
    -type f \
    ! -exec lsof -n "{}" \; \
    -exec cp "{}" /fileshare/Zund/zund1/ \; \
    -exec chmod -R 777 /fileshare/Zund/zund1/ \; \
    -exec cp "{}" /fileshare/Zund/zund2/ \; \
    -exec chmod -R 777 /fileshare/Zund/zund2/ \; \
    -exec rm "{}" \;.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Cheers

Comment: Is that dot at the end at purpose? Did you already try to debug the problem by yourself? (for example by reducing the complexity of the find command) Any insights with that?

Comment: You probably should also escape that exclamation mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Dot in the end of the script.

I think, that your problem in this dot. For example following command gives the same error
 `find ./ -type f -exec ls \;.`. What is the purpose of the dot here?

From man on `find`:

> -exec command  ;
> Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command
>   until an argument consisting of `;' is encountered. ...

I assume, that dot in the end (instead of ;) breaks parsing of the last argument and you
 receive the error message.

Comment: Thanks - this is the correct answer. The removal of the dot at the end, ie having ";" instead of ";." was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: Your FreeNas box uses a much more simple shell, which does not feature history expansion.

Therefore you do not have to escape that exclamation point on that shell but you need to do this on bash. - Otherwise it would interpret it as history expansion.

The bash man page says:

```
QUOTING
   Quoting  is used to remove the special meaning of certain characters or words
   to the shell.  Quoting can be used to disable special treatment  for  special
   characters,  to  prevent reserved words from being recognized as such, and to
   prevent parameter expansion.

   Each of the metacharacters listed above under DEFINITIONS has special meaning
   to the shell and must be quoted if it is to represent itself.

   When  the  command  history  expansion facilities are being used (see HISTORY
   EXPANSION below), the history expansion character, usually !, must be  quoted
   to prevent history expansion.
```